# Derivative $f'(0)$ when $f'(x)=\frac{A}{x} $?

Tags: real-analysis

$f(x)=\ln^2 x - 6  \ln x $

$f'(x) = \frac{2\ln x-6}{x}              $

$f''(x) = \frac{8-2\ln x}{x^{2}}  $

What happens for $x=0$? Do I have to prove from definition 
$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}  {x-0}$ if the derivative in this point exist or it is it obvious that it doesn't exist?

Comment: The function is not defined at $0$ so it has no derivative.

Comment: Yeah, if you can't say what $f(0)$ is, you are gonna have a hard time defining $f'(0)$ using that definition.

Comment: You have to look at the domain of the non-derived function, if a number n isn't in the domain, it won't be in the derivative formula